# pass view (php file) as string to variable js in registerJS in yii 2

Tags: javascript, view, yii2, render

I want to pass view Of the type php to variable js in registerJS
like here but I can't

```
var view_train = '<?=$this->render("_view")?>';
```

after run i see this error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

how can i use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple JSON encoding:

```
<?php
$viewAsString = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($this->render("_view"));
$script = <<<EOF
    var view_train = $viewAsString;
EOF
$this->registerJs($script);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the code `<?=$this->render("_view")?>` must be returning multi-line string or html data which isn't supported in JS within single or double quotes. Use [backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) symbol instead of single quotes like below

```
var view_train = `<?=$this->render("_view")?>`;
```